# Fix sticky navigation bar to appear where it started upon scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a floating navigation bar that appears when you scroll upwards and disappears when you scroll down.

My only problem is that the bar starts not on top of the website, but underneath a header.
With this code I managed to make it appear/disappear, but it doesn't revert back to it's original position upon scrollin all the way up. It just stays stuck on top of the browser window.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If scrolled down && past navbar, add class .nav-up
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('sticknav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('sticknav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

My css for the navigation bar is this

```
sticknav {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
}

.nav-up {
    top: -40px;
    position: fixed;
}

.nav-down {
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

and stickynav is my navigation bar.

I know it's because I loop it in a position: fixed; state but I can't wrap my head around how to fix this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[CSS sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky) is a good option for this. The only downside is no [IE11 support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

```js
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  // Scroll more than delta
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

  // If scrolled down && past navbar, add class .nav-up
  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight) {
    // Scroll Down
    $('.sticknav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
  } else {
    // Scroll Up
    if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('.sticknav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    }
  }

  lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
.sticknav {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}

.sticknav {
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

.nav-up {
  top: -40px;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-down {
  top: 0px;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buffer">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor</p>
</div>
<header class="sticknav"></header>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: tried adding it and put your jqery under my
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
and then replaced my css with yours, but it didn't work.
Is the html part you posted relevant in any way? Sorry I'm really a beginner when it comes to web design

Comment: @URK Your css has `sticknav` which I believe should be `.sticknav` but I'm not sure if that's the cause. Can you add your html to the question?

Comment: it's a really big block of code, but I just put it in <sticknav> BLOCK OF CODE </sticknav>. Do I have to make sticknav a class then?

Comment: @URK `<sticknav></sticknav>` is not a valid HTML tag. You should change that to a valid tag like `<div class="sticknav"></div>` or `<header class="sticknav"></header>`

Comment: YES VERY NICE. That was the issue, thank you very very much! It works now

Comment: is there a way to make the transition when scrolling down seamless?
When scrolling up it's perfect, but when scrolling down it takes a while to hide

Comment: Not sure @URK, the transition seems smooth in both directions in my post. Does it work for you in my answer?

Comment: it works perfectly fine, it's just nitpicking at this point. Just when I scroll down it sticks to the top a bit first instead of instantly, smoothly hiding like as if it wouldn't even start sticking.